# qemu-kvm 5.2 On Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, kvm-virtualization, openstack, qemu, nova

I am using ubuntu 20.04 for openstack compute nodes. I see the version qemu-kvm version 4.2 on ubuntu repos. How can I install latest qemu-kvm version 5.2 on ubuntu 20.04. Will there be any possibility that its going to be available on ubunutu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Not in proper 20.04 for many reasons in the [SRU policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) making this impossible.

But sometimes (if features are needed) the [UCA](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive) has new builds.

And then there is the independent [server-backports](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-server/+archive/ubuntu/server-backports) which exists exactly for a need like yours - to backport the latest Ubuntu virt-stack (and other things) to the two last LTS releases 20.04/18.04.